# SQL Server stored procedure Isolate transaction has been cancelled

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to update tables. I get this error when the stored procedure is executed from a different PC at the same time.

> System.Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): La transaction d'isolement d'instantané a été abandonnée en raison d'un conflit de mise à jour. Vous ne pouvez pas utiliser l'isolement d'instantané pour accéder à la table 'dbo.Journee' directement ou indirectement dans la base de données 'PlanningGestion' afin de mettre à jour, de supprimer ou d'insérer la ligne modifiée ou supprimée par une autre transaction. Réexécutez la transaction ou changez le niveau d'isolement pour l'instruction de mise à jour/suppression

Is it possible to specify that the system needs to wait until the end of the first stored procedure execution then start the new one? As FIFO.

Or do I have to use a different way to do that?

PS: my stored procedure updates from subquery

```
update Journee 
set UVGlobalJournee = (select 
                           case
                               when max(E.UVGlobale) is null
                                   then 0 
                                   else max(E.UVGlobale) 
                           end
                       from 
                           Examen E 
                       inner join 
                           IT_Journee_Examen IT on E.IdExamen = IT.IDEXAMEN 
                       where 
                           Journee.IdJournee = IT.IDJOURNEE) 
where Test = '1'  
  and Journee.IdJournee = @IdJournee
```

Comment: [Are error messages required to be posted in English?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402217/1839439) Please format the question properly and explain what the error message says

Comment: Your approach is giving off a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Whilst we could help you solve this exact problem, I think there would be far more to gain from re-designing your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an explicit transaction, with read committed isolation level on you procedure.
Assuming the procedure code is only what is on the question, it would be something like:

```
create or alter procedure name_of_your_procedure AS
begin
set transaction isolation level read committed
begin transaction
update Journee 
set UVGlobalJournee = (select 
                           case
                               when max(E.UVGlobale) is null
                                   then 0 
                                   else max(E.UVGlobale) 
                           end
                       from 
                           Examen E 
                       inner join 
                           IT_Journee_Examen IT on E.IdExamen = IT.IDEXAMEN 
                       where 
                           Journee.IdJournee = IT.IDJOURNEE) 
where Test = '1'  
  and Journee.IdJournee = @IdJournee
commit transaction
end
```

If, running on a database with RCSI enabled, you change beginning of this procedure to:

```
set transaction isolation level snapshot
```

and execute it concurrently, you will get the same error on the question. With read committed, I couldn't get that error.

Comment: Thanks you. And in this case, the error will disapears ? new sp will wait the end of previous ?

Comment: This doesn't work if RCSI is enabled, see docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Read Committed Snapshot (`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option), setting `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` has no effect.

Instead add the `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` table hint to the table being updated.

Note that you can still get read skew, unless you use `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` in all the other tables as well

```
create or alter procedure name_of_your_procedure AS
begin

update Journee WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
set UVGlobalJournee = (select 
                           case
                               when max(E.UVGlobale) is null
                                   then 0 
                                   else max(E.UVGlobale) 
                           end
                       from 
                           Examen E 
                       inner join 
                           IT_Journee_Examen IT on E.IdExamen = IT.IDEXAMEN 
                       where 
                           Journee.IdJournee = IT.IDJOURNEE) 
where Test = '1'  
  and Journee.IdJournee = @IdJournee

end
```

Comment: Maybe I can crite query in different way. If I do variable table containing all value of my subquery, then execute cursor rto update line by line . Maybe I will securte transaction no ?

Comment: No that won't work, not sure why you thought it would. You should [read up](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) on SNAPSHOT and update conflicts